# permission denied on installing lxd via snap

Tags: lxd

I'm trying to install LXD on my Ubuntu via this tutorial https://docs.conjure-up.io/devel/en/user-manual#users-of-lxd in it says I have to follow these steps:

1. `sudo snap install lxd` (no problem in installing)
2. `/snap/bin/lxd init` (I get the below error)

> Error: Failed to connect to local LXD: Get http://unix.socket/1.0:
>   dial unix /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket: connect: permission
>   denied

can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like for some reason the permissions on the `unix.socket` are not correct. (I tried this myself and works fine). The permission on my `unix.socket` look like this:

```
srw-rw----  1 root lxd     0 Nov  7 18:02 unix.socket
```

I would try:

```
sudo chown root:lxd /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket
sudo chmod 664 /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket
sudo chmod u+s /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket
```

If not then it could be an issue with your `/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/` directory. Does it even exist?

Comment: Yes, this directory exists, but after I ran your instructions nothing changed.

Comment: What linux distro are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS - xenial

Comment: So I should upgrade mine?

Comment: I also tried it on 18.04 and the problem wasn't solved.

Comment: @ksadjad I was using `lxd` inside VBox, I don't mine much about security so give it public permission: `sudo chmod 666 /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket` , Another solution add your user to `lxd` group .

Answer (score 0):

Proper way according to Ubuntu [page](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/containers-lxd) is:

1. `sudo apt install lxd`
2. `sudo lxd init`
3. `sudo adduser <your-user> lxd`
4. `newgrp lxd`

Now you are ready to launch:

- `lxc launch ubuntu:22.04 test`